# Ajax JSON multi array - determing array index contains specified values

Tags: json, jquery

I am returning a JSON multi array from PHP via JQuery Ajax, and want to determine which array contains a value in order to access values in that array (likewise for the other arrays - up to three arrays altogethebeing returned.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "scripts/get_model_imaging_report.php",
data: {
        case_id:caseId,
        level:currentLevel
},
dataType: "json",
success: function(returnedData) {

}
});
```

PHP;

```
$case = $_POST['case_id'];
$level = $_POST['level'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM model_image_report WHERE case_fk = '$case' AND level = '$level'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
        'image_report_type' => $row['image_report_type'],
        'subject' => $row['subject'],
        'clinical' =>  $row['clinical'],
        'study_type' =>  $row['study_type'],
        'report' =>  $row['report'],
        'comment' =>  $row['comment'],
        'image' =>  $row['image'],
        'image_annotated' =>  $row['image_annotated']
        );
} 
echo json_encode($data);
```

The key I need to check is 'image_report_type' and the values can be 'nuclear', 'radiology' and 'ultrasound'.

Then I need to access values in those arrays where 'image_report_type' == 'nuclear' for example.

The JSON array looks like:

```
[{"image_report_type":"nuclear","subject":"Brain Scan","clinical":"Clinical","study_type":"nuclear image scan.","report":"Report","comment":"Comment","image":"original_image_case_3_level_1_nuclear.jpg","image_annotated":"annotated_image_case_3_level_1_nuclear.png"},{"image_report_type":"ultrasound","subject":"Brain Scan","clinical":"Clinical","study_type":"Ultrasound image scan.","report":"Report","comment":"Comment","image":"original_image_case_3_level_1_nuclear.jpg","image_annotated":"annotated_image_case_3_level_1_nuclear.png"}]
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to check if the field 'image_report_type' is set/has a value in order to add it to the $data array?

Comment: I have up to 3 arrays in the multi array.  I want to identify which array contains, for example,  "image_report_type":"nuclear", so that I can access values in that array, likewise for any other array that contains "image_report_type":"ultrasound or "image_report_type":"radiology""

Comment: Are you looking for performance? In case it's not very important, jQuery is your best friend for data trasversing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

```
function(returnedData) {
  $.each(returnedData, function(i,o) {
      if (o.image_report_type == "nuclear") {
         //Do Something
      }
  });
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benashby/tN7bb/) Demonstrating this technique

Comment: Thanks, looks like this might do it, I'll give it a go.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straight forward answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/mN4LF/3/

Javascript

```
function findIndexOf(data, searchField, searchValue){
    var result = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i][searchField] == searchValue){
            result.push(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```